# Replace control template in toggle button on change state

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to create a flexible toggle button control. On toggle button "IsChecked" property "true", I would add two another buttons.

I have obtained this result by setting control template. But now how can I set default toggle button template (in this case toggle template is parrent) after button clicked? Toggle button should has "IsChecked" property set to false after undo.

XAML code:

```
<ToggleButton Content="Delete">
<ToggleButton.Style>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="ToggleButton.Content" Value="Stops" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToggleButton.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Button Command="{Binding ConditionalAcceptCommand}" Grid.Column="0">
                                    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/check_mark24.png"/>
                                </Button>
                                <Button Grid.Column="1">
                                    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/delete24.png"/>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ToggleButton.Style>
```

Thanks

Comment: Post some XAML code please.

Comment: Added to main post. The goal is:

When I click secound button then toggle button control template will back to default. It is possible? Maybe my idea is not so good?